# Sort array of strings lexicographically based on last alphabet - String index out of range -1 Exception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
package mediumchallenge;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class sortarrayofstringsbylength{

    private static class comparelengths implements Comparator<String>{

        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (arg0.length()- arg1.length());
        }
    }

    private static class lastchar implements Comparator<String>{

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (s1.charAt(s1.length()-1) - s2.charAt(s2.length()-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String arr[] = {"abd" , "abc","y" , "rtyuodfdjfhd","weq","wge",""};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

        // sorts according to length of string  
        Arrays.sort(arr, new comparelengths());
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
        //sorts lexicographically according to last letter  
        Arrays.sort(arr, new lastchar());
        for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
            System.out.println(arr[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to sort the string array based on last character of each string using comparator. It's giving me String index out of range -1 exception

Comment: What is the length of your last String in your array? What do you think this does `s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)` if the length is 0?

Comment: its an empty string . So 0.

Comment: So what do you think `s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)` does for a String of length 0?

Comment: oops. So I'll have to add a check for that condition.

Comment: do I just not allow empty string ?

Comment: That depends. You could make an argument that it should be either the very first or very last one in the array. (The most convincing argument I've seen is for the former.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to check the lengths themselves for zero.

- if `s2` is empty and `s1` is not empty, `s2` should go behind `s1` so we return `-1`.
- if `s1` is empty and `s2` is not empty, `s1` should go behind `s2` so we return `1`.
- if `s2` is empty and `s1` is empty, they are `equal` and we should return `0`.

Below an example of such an implementation:

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

// Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer 
// as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

                if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() > 0)return 1; 
                if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() > 0)return -1; 
                if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() == 0)return 0; 

                return (s1.charAt(s1.length()-1) - s2.charAt(s2.length()-1));
            }
```

Basically you need to decide if you will allow empty strings and what action to take when they are encountered (e.g. push them below).

**If you want empty strings to be first use:**

```
if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() > 0)return -1; 
if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() > 0)return 1; 
if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() == 0)return 0;
```

If you want empty strings to be last use:

```
if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() > 0)return 1; 
if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() > 0)return -1; 
if(s2.length() == 0 && s1.length() == 0)return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

String arr[] = {"abd" , "abc","y" , "rtyuodfdjfhd","weq","wge",""};

The last element is "", it's length is zero. 
The code "s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)" will throw String index out of range -1 exception.